# How to read process memory in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, memory, pid

So I have a game's PID and I want to be able to read from the `/proc/PID/mem` file but I do not know how to. I am doing this in Python3 also.

Comment: Believe the Python solution would follow same flow as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux . See the C-code block at the end of the first answer that involves ptrace, Haven't done this myself, but can test it out if you're still stuck. Is the Process ID you're reading from the same Process or different?

Comment: it is from the same process